# Send email with pdf attachment with pl sql

Tags: oracle, email, pdf, plsql

I normally use utl_smtp to send emails in pl/sql, but recently I've had to send a pdf file as attachment and utl_smtp does not allow it. Can you help me on how to send one in pl/sql?

Answer (score 4):

An attachment it's just base64 encoded text in the body of the message separated from the rest of the text with a boundary section. So if you can send text, you can also send attachments of any type.

Here you have a procedure for sending an email with an attachment.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE send_mail (p_to          IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_from        IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_subject     IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_text_msg    IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_attach_name IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_attach_mime IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_attach_blob IN BLOB DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_smtp_host   IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_smtp_port   IN NUMBER DEFAULT 25)
AS
  l_mail_conn   UTL_SMTP.connection;
  l_boundary    VARCHAR2(50) := '----=*#abc1234321cba#*=';
  l_step        PLS_INTEGER  := 12000; -- make sure you set a multiple of 3 not higher than 24573
BEGIN
  l_mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(p_smtp_host, p_smtp_port);
  UTL_SMTP.helo(l_mail_conn, p_smtp_host);
  UTL_SMTP.mail(l_mail_conn, p_from);
  UTL_SMTP.rcpt(l_mail_conn, p_to);

  UTL_SMTP.open_data(l_mail_conn);

  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Date: ' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'To: ' || p_to || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'From: ' || p_from || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Subject: ' || p_subject || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Reply-To: ' || p_from || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'MIME-Version: 1.0' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="' || l_boundary || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

  IF p_text_msg IS NOT NULL THEN
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, p_text_msg);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  END IF;

  IF p_attach_name IS NOT NULL THEN
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: ' || p_attach_mime || '; name="' || p_attach_name || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || p_attach_name || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

    FOR i IN 0 .. TRUNC((DBMS_LOB.getlength(p_attach_blob) - 1 )/l_step) LOOP
      UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(DBMS_LOB.substr(p_attach_blob, l_step, i * l_step + 1))));
    END LOOP;

    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  END IF;

  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || '--' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.close_data(l_mail_conn);

  UTL_SMTP.quit(l_mail_conn);
END;
/
```

Comment: I have read though that "The UTL_SMTP package is best suited for sending small, text only e-mails from the database. " and the file that I am handling is not small, say 18.4 kb.

Comment: I don't know why it is best suited for small mails. With UTL_MAIL you do have a limit of 32K for the mail's body, but this doesn't happen with UTL_SMTP; http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_smtp.htm#i1004292

Comment: This is working perfectly fine for me. @fjoralba OP, please mark this as an answer if it helped you.